# Using multiple conditions with the while loop in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and have started making some fun little games to remember how it works. I have come across an area where I want to use more than one condition in a while loop and can't work out how to do so. I have seen on here some people doing it with numbers etc but I'm using letters and nothing I do or search for seems to work. This is what I have got so far. The idea is that the person chooses A or B (in lower or uppercase) and if they don't, that it loops back to input again.

```
ANS = input("\tA/B: ")
if ANS == "A":
    print("They beat you up and stole all of your stuff. You should have run away.") 
    del BAG[:]
    print("You now have", len(BAG), "items in your bag.")                             
elif ANS == "a":
    print("They beat you up and stole all of your stuff. You should have run away.") 
    del BAG[:]
    print("You now have", len(BAG), "items in your bag.")                            
elif ANS == "B":
    print("You got away but they stole something from you.")                         
    ran_item = random.choice(BAG)
    BAG.remove(ran_item)
    print("You now have", len(BAG), "items in your bag")                             
    print("They are:", BAG)
elif ANS == "b":
    print("You got away but they stole something from you.")                         
    ran_item = random.choice(BAG)
    BAG.remove(ran_item)
    print("You now have", len(BAG), "items in your bag")                             
    print("They are:", BAG)
while ANS != "A" or "a" or "B" or "b":
    print("You must make a choice...")
    ANS = input("\tA/B: ")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while ANS not in ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b']:
    print...
```

or more generally

```
while ANS != 'A' and ANS != 'a' and ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition of your while-loop is being interpreted by Python like this:

```
while (ANS != "A") or ("a") or ("B") or ("b"):
```

Moreover, it will always evaluate to `True` because non-empty strings always evaluate to `True`.

---

To fix the problem, you can use [`not in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) instead:

```
while ANS not in ("A", "a", "B", "b"):
```

`not in` will test if `ANS` can be found in the tuple `("A", "a", "B", "b")`.

---

You may also wish to use [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) here to shorten the length of the tuple:

```
while ANS.lower() not in ("a", "b"):
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of to do it in this case would be:

```
while ANS[0].lower() not in 'ab':
    ....
```